# Removed operating system blank screen with flashing underscore

Tags: 14.04, boot, flash

I recently used DBAN boot and nuke to completely wipe a PC I was planning on giving away. I now want to install Ubuntu on it before I hand it over. I've wrote the iso to a usb however when I set the correct BIOS settings I just get a flashing underscore.

If I don't put in the USB I simply get the message 'no operating system found'. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.com :-) What BIOS settings do you mean exactly? Is it really still an old BIOS system or does it already have UEFI? Can you check whether you can boot from the USB drive on another machine?

Comment: Hello, I've set it to boot from usb its a sony vaio which is around 4 years old. I'll check the usb now

Comment: Just checked and installation works fine on my other pc

Comment: Do you use the correct architecture (32/64bit) for your downloaded iso? When in doubt, 32bit should work on both. Do you mind burning a DVD and try installing from that rather than from the USB device? There are less things someone can do wrong...

Comment: @ByteCommander: I'm sure a 4 year old Sony Vaio supports AMD64 instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used LinuxLive USB Creator www.linuxliveusb.com/ and it worked perfectly